# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool server utilities
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white or transparent

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/ads/display/6840).

Comment: I hear tale that there's [this nifty new alerting system called Bosun](http://blog.serverfault.com/2014/11/10/announcing-bosun/) - Maybe someone who knows more about it should get an artistically-talented person to make an ad for it? :-P

Comment: (not complaining, just curious) Why do we have to have a 1px border and few (none?) of the x.SE sites have that requirement?

Comment: Would an Enterprise Content Management server be on-topic? I was thinking of adding http://nemakiware.com

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It's open source. I don't see a problem with it. But that doesn't guarantee that everyone else will like it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8576/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 16):

[image: Configuration Management]

Comment: …my deployment server melted. :(

Comment: @voretaq7 Needs better cooling in your datacenter, clearly.

Comment: <throws another database server on the fire> What? I can't hear you over the server alarm beeps!

Comment: Lots of databases, databases burn *good*.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Bareos - Open Source Data Protection]

Answer (score 13):

[image: FreeBSD - more than Creation]

Comment: Stolen from Scott's 2014 ad (I'll see about coming up with a new banner though, I feel dirty recycling...)

Comment: Scott stole from me... who stole from the official post card templates.

Comment: @ChrisS So we're all [filthy little thieves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0zte5Z8tJU)?

Answer (score 11):

[image: Data integrity-oriented filesystem]

Answer (score 7):

[image: FreeIPA: Identity Management done right]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Fedora Server: The latest technology. A stable foundation.]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Fedora Cloud: Lean. Powerful. Everycloud ready.]

Answer (score 2):

[image: NemakiWare: NoSQL, CMIS-compliant Enterprise Content Management. Small start, scalable, open source]

Answer (score 2):

[image: vim's rebirth for the 21st century]

Comment: Images must have a 1px border around them if they have a white background.

Answer (score -22):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Which isn't going to happen, -18 speaks pretty far to that.

Comment: We need to do better this year: [Unix.SE beat us with -21](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2550/29792). Let's get cracking people.

Comment: @AndrewB There is a [new competitor this year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19015).

Comment: BAD TWITTER BOT! BAD! GO STAND IN THE CORNER!