# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool server utilities
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/ads/display/9028).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2018](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9243/community-promotion-ads-2018)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Bareos Open Source Data Protection]

Answer (score 3):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Comment: Upvoted on unix.SE because it's good code. I'm abstaining from an upvote on SF as I don't consider citation nags that must be disabled once for every (user,system) permutation to be enterprise ready.

Comment: I assume you do not mind paying for enterprise ready software. Are you aware that you can buy a version that does not have the citation notice?

Comment: You assume much about most UNIX IT shops, unfortunately. Ops teams are under constant pressure to reduce opex expenditures every year, and no one is going to approve an expense to remove a nag that isn't relevant to departments without a public face to begin with. While you're certainly welcome to manage your project as you see fit, please understand that this is valid criticism when you're linking to a project which does *not* advertise itself as a commercial solution on a business IT site.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Microsoft Virtual Academy]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Fedora Server: The latest technology and a stable foundation for your apps and services.]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Create and run applications in Linux containers.]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Check out the Area 51 DevOps Proposal!]

Comment: I don't like (anonymous) downvotes ... How can anybody ppossibly be against this kind of ad ... without leaving a comment?

Comment: Sorry to "stalk" you around here ... but I was just curious if you succeeded in making your image "dynamic", ie to make the nr of days go up every day. But it looks like it doesn't show "10 days" now yet (the nr of days to day is 10 .. time flies ...). So unless you want to manually tweak this image every day, maybe replace the "9 days in beta" with something like "In beta since early March", or otherwise just remove that info from your image?

Comment: No worries :) I'ts not "my image" - I needed an imgur copy the 1st time, but then I edited its url to point to the area51's png (check the edit history). The image is already dynamic, but from what I observed it's refreshed about once a day, so it's usually 1 day behind the reality, sometimes even 2, maybe due to cacheing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Server Fault Review Queue]

Comment: Referring: [Have we given up on the review queue?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9105/have-we-given-up-on-the-review-queue). Motivated by the [same solution](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9557/32426) for the same problem on another site.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ![Visit Stack Apps!]

Answer (score -5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: dear god, people have actually been upvoting this abomination. The only thing this twitter account has ever been *reliably* useful for is for posting off topic questions that need to be closed.

Comment: @RobMoir I always though this twitter account was run by our fellow SF admin that work at SO. 