# Have we given up on the review queue?

Tags: discussion

I'm guilty...I've given up.  I simply don't frequent SF enough anymore due to the job requirements to be a daily contributor.

But I was actually pretty shocked to see the shape the review queue is in.  I remember when it was kept to a minimum daily.

Has the SF community given up on the review queue?  Have the top reviewers decided the custodial efforts simply aren't worth it?  Or is it simply one data point that means nothing overall?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a longer answer than "yes"?

Comment: @HopelessN00b - from you?  Nope.  ;)

Comment: I, for one, haven't visited the review queue in months.

Comment: ^^^ Same here. Part is  that I started working at new job and have less time, part that the review queue is intended to be the community process and not everything needs the mod hammer.

Comment: I've looked into it a few weeks back, only to find I still strongly dislike the review system. Also, what @HBruijn said.

Comment: It's not that bad. I check it from time to time, but at least all category except first post is good. For reference for over 2 year, I almost never seen the close queue under 100 (max was around 300). Maybe a sign new user contribute, as for the first post's queue I never check it. (As for me if it pass the low quality/spam's check, it's not that bad, I'am surely not the only one that think like that).

Comment: I pretty much gave up on close votes, but I look at reopen every now and then.  The current # of close reviews isn't too bad - it got up to almost 200 a few months ago and has since gone down.

Comment: NO. But I'm leaderless...so yes.

Comment: I'm generally against closing questions, so I don't visit that queue because I'm against most of the requests and it's just frustrating, but I think *First Posts* deserves more attention.

Comment: I've been busy UPGRADING ALL THE THINGS, but will hopefully spend more time here now that I'm finished.

Comment: perhaps we can include multiple rewards for every 1k of first post checked.

personally i stopped after hitting the ~1k gold medal.
additionally its way too many clicks to just say: crap, delete, crap delete.

Comment: Most Stack Overflow reviewers would give one of their organs to see the Close Vote queue there at 135.

Comment: A few folks have been hammering away at First Posts reviews for the last few weeks.  The backlog has been going down steadily.  Thanks for all of the effort.

Comment: I've been busy with a fresh offspring (that is now no longer fresh) and a new job (that is now old)... So I guess what I'm saying is, I looked away for a second and never got the motivation to return.

Answer (score 16):

To give an answer; Yes for some and no for others. (As told in my comment, except new post, other queue seem ok)

For me we seem to loose old contributor, while we cant much get new users to help there, but there is a fact that does not help us;

Something that I hate is the fact that MSE seem to have dropped the ball for the review queue for mobile user. As for me I mostly use the site on my mobile phone, and MSE never integrated that feature there ([Review option on mobile phone not available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available))

Giving a well documented answer is hard on the mobile app, but reviewing would be an easy task, thus I think MSE don't help to get new reviewer.

There is a output, you see the mobile site usage, as almost %50 ... so MSE seem to have miss the boat there.

[image]

Comment: I'd love to see the review queue integrated into mobile. It's an easy thing to spend a few minutes on over the weekend, especially if it were in my pocket.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is that there is a limit of 20 requests that can be examined per person in a 24-hour period per review.  Unless there are lots of participants, review queues may grow rapidly depending on entries.

Maybe these limits could be upped a bit more?

Comment: To those who downvoted this...why?

Comment: I think it is a good idea. Sites suffering similar problems, it was suggested many times on the SE meta. The SE doesn't want it, as I can remember their arguments, they fear the review quality will decrease. In my opinion, they could easily fix it by elevating the audit frequency, and this is what they should do. Note, I think there is also a different, but related problem, and it is that I think also the mod customs / policies should be adapted to reflect the changes in the world of the system administration and the site visitors in the last years.